# Access to model object by EL in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, jsp, jstl

Here is my markup, I am using jtsl core tag

```
<c:forEach var="attr" items="${attributes}">
    <c:when test='${attr.controlType == "textField"}'>
        <script>createTextField("${attr}");</script>
        </c:when>
</c:forEach>
```

So the "attributes" is a list of objects which resides in the model.

I want to call the createTextField function and I want access to the "attr"
in that function.

Here is my function, but I can't get access to the object, says it is undefined.

```
function createTextField(object) {
    document.write(object.name);        
}
```

Any ideas? would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not going to work. Java and JavaScript doesn't run in the same environment. You're basically passing `attr.toString()` to the JavaScript function which look by default like `com.example.ClassName@hashcode`. The JavaScript `String` object doesn't have a `name` property.

There are basically two ways to get it to work:

1. You need to convert the Java object as represented by `#{attr}` to a string which conforms the JavaScript object notation (also known as [JSON](http://json.org)). E.g.

   ```
   <script>createTextField(${attr.asJson});</script>
   ```

   with something like (with little help of [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)):

   ```
   public String getAsJson() {
       return new Gson().toJson(this);
   }
   ```

   You can of course also manually build it using `StringBuilder` or something. JSON format isn't that hard.
2. Pass only the property/properties of interest as long as they can be represented as `String`. E.g.

   ```
   <script>createTextField("${attr.name}");</script>
   ```

   with

   ```
   function createTextField(name) {
       document.write(name);        
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, in this case option 2 will not work because I have a lot of fields in the object that I need in the function so, I have to use option one, but I am confused, I know what JSON is but dont understand what you meant by number 1. Can you please explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: What part exactly don't you understand? Option 1 just tells you that you should convert the Java object to JSON so that you can easily print it as a valid JS function argument.

Comment: how to convert that object to a JSON, and then how to extract the values from that JSON within that JS function

Comment: Uh, just use Gson or any arbirary Java based JSON parser API to convert a Java object to JSON string, or create a `String` in JSON format yourself with `StringBuilder`. The format should ultimately end up something like `{"name":"somevalue", "otherproperty":"othervalue"}` etc. Your JS `createTextField()` function can be kept untouched as it already retrieves a valid JS object when using JSON. You said that you know what JSON is, but after all you apparently don't understand JSON at all. What exactly is your problem?